# why does Fawn throwing an error like 'The provided mongoose instance is invalid' to Mongoose library version ^6.9.1

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have written the same code as the document suggests.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Fawn = require("fawn");

mongoose
  .connect("mongodb://0.0.0.0:27017/rental")
  .then(() => console.log("Database rental connected"))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err.message));

Fawn.init(mongoose);
```

And the error is:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\mongo-rental\node_modules\fawn\lib\fawn.js:30
        throw new Error("The provided mongoose instance is invalid");
        ^

Error: The provided mongoose instance is invalid
    at Object.init (C:\xampp\htdocs\mongo-rental\node_modules\fawn\lib\fawn.js:30:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\xampp\htdocs\mongo-rental\index.js:15:6)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1218:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1272:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1081:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47
```

I have followed the document and still getting the same error.
I have already removed and reinstalled both the library two times.

Comment: mongoose.connect is async, try awaiting it.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix this error by adding my mongodb connection string instead of inputting passing `mongoose`:

So instead of putting:

```js
Fawn.init(mongoose)
```

Do this instead:

```js
Fawn.init('mongodb://{YourConnectionString}/{YourDBName}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this by changing **obj.modelScemas** to **obj.Schema** in **isMongoose(obj)** function.

**Fawn** version = **2.1.5**

Steps to make changes:

1. goto "*node_modules/fawn/lib/fawn.js*"
2. Scroll down until you see "*function isMongoose(obj) { ... }*".
3. change "*obj.modelScemas*" to "*obj.Schema*" -> **save**
4. Come back to project's root folder and run the index file -> node index.js

**Note:** this is not a recommended solution. It is just a work around until the issue gets fixed in newer version.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that there has been no update of FAWN since 6 years if you check the documentation in Github.
instead of FAWN you can use transaction since MongoDb and Mongoose support transactions.
this is how I resolve it myself

```
const db = await mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/playground').asPromise();
const session = await db.startSession();

try {
    await session.withTransaction(async () => {
      rental.save();
      decNumberInStock(movie._id)
      res.send(rental);
    });
  } finally {
    await session.endSession();
    await db.close();
    console.log('ok')
  }
```

in movies model you can define decNumberInstock :

```
async function decNumberInStock(movieId) {
const movie = await Movie.findByIdAndUpdate(movieId , {
    $inc : { numberInStock : -1}
});
movie.save();}
```

Answer (score -1):

I resolved this issue with this documentation [enter link description here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fawn#fawn_init)

Comment: Hi, do not use only links while answering; links may become invalid, and  your answer  would become unusable for all of us